# c# equivalent of c++ vector<int>

Tags: c#, arrays, vector

This is c++ code:

```
std::vector<int> T(256,-1);
for (int i=0; i<64; i++) T["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"[i]] = i;
```

What is c# equivalent of this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var T = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 256).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    T["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"[i]] = i;
```